# Why do I get an Error: EPERM when using create-react-app with npx?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, create-react-app, npx

I'm trying to start to use "create-react-app" on my windows machine, but I'm not able to make it work.

I'm using the `npx create-react-app appname` command on the following system

```
Windows: 10
Nodejs: 13.6.0
npm/npx: 6.13.6
```

Previously I had "create-react-app" globally installed (already un-installed globally as suggest).
Also, I already have un-installed nodejs and re-installed it, the problem maintains.

I get the following error message: 
where the ** are this is replacing my username. The username is having a space in between.(not sure if that makes  a difference)

```
    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\*****'
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorMessage (C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-message.js:38:39)
    at errorHandler (C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:201:13)
    at C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
    at C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
    at C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
    at f (C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:171:20)
   C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

   TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Users\***** **********\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:164:25)
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 7
```